# Calculation of RMS current in half wave rectifier

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics

While calculating RMS current in [half wave rectifier](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=half+wave+rectifier), why we will consider only half wave that means only we consider the limits 0 to pi. But here RMS current is for AC input..so why don't we consider and calculate as 0 to 2pi? Please clarify this.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

We only consider the current from $0$ to $\pi$ since the current from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ is effectively 0. Consider a sinusoidal A.C. current $I = I_0\sin t$ (assuming the period is $2\pi$ as in your question), when there is a half wave rectifier, current can only flow in one direction. Thus any part of $I$ that is negative becomes zero. The current in the circuit becomes

$I =\begin{cases} 
      \hfill I_0\sin t    \hfill & 0 \leq t < \pi \\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \pi \leq t < 2\pi \\
  \end{cases}.$

So it is the same to consider this function from $0$ to $2\pi$, or the original function from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: But still small clarification I RMS is the specially for which we have taken as an input to the rectifier so calculation refers to input that means which is having both positive and negative so why we are not considering both..because this is calculation which we are doing for the wave before giving to the rectifier.

Comment: @VasanthaMeghana yes, but that's before the rectifier is in the circuit. If the current source is connected to the rectifier, then the input and the output will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

RMS means square mean root 
. i.e. take square add and take mean then take square root. If you take square of ac i.e. sinusoidal waveform the parts from $0$ to $\pi$ become identical to the part between $\pi$ to $2.\pi$. Hence if you add from $0$ to $n.\pi$ and divide by n you will essentially left with one lobe.

That's why you can only use one lobe to get the RMS value

I hope this will help.